# Android Studio Giraffe - Compact Mode missing

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I updated to the new **Android Studio Giraffe** and tried the new UI.
However I'm missing the compact mode.

Documentation states this can be found in the view mode
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/03/new-ui-enhancements-in-intellij-idea-2023-1/

but I seem to miss this option.

My View | Appearance menu does not show this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
This is a known issue for the current version.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-298485

It will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Are there some workaround now?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2 (the latest currently) and still no fix. But there might be some beta versions for that.